# Populating dropdown menu after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am aware that AJAX works asynchronously (that is what the “A” stands for). I moved all the code that depends on the result of the AJAX call inside the success callback. However after the call is being made, I am not getting the select dropdwon box to populate with any data. How can I populate the select dropdown menu after the ajax call?

Jquery/Ajax

```
<script>
function showFields(option){  
    var content = '';
    for (var i = 1; i <= option; i++){

    function addNewCourse() {
    var data;
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "coursesOffered.php",
         data: { value : option},
         success: function(data){
            //alert(data);
            //console.log(data);
            content += '<select id="coursename_'+i+'" name="coursename_'+i+'" class="course_list"><option value="" >--- Select ---</option>"';
            content += data;
            content += '</select></br>';
         }
        });
    }                  
    addNewCourse();
    }
}
</script>
```

coursesOffered.php

```
try {
    $db_con = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $db_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
} 
$course_query = $db_con->prepare("SELECT course_id, course_name FROM courses_selection_list;");
$course_query->execute();
$data = $course_query->fetchAll();
foreach ($data as $row){
    //dropdown values pulled from database
    echo '<option value="' . $row['course_id'] . ':'.$row['course_name'].'">' . $row['course_name'] . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: @SridharR what do you mean?

Comment: what happens when you do console.log(data) in your success?

Comment: @yogesh I get the values for the dropdwon menu. Check this [DEMO](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/courses_stat.php)

Comment: you placed return statement on wrong position, see modified answer with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comments in code:

```
function showFields(option) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= option; i++) {

    (function(i) {

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "coursesOffered.php",
        data: {
          value: option
        },
        success: function (data) {
          var content += '<select id="coursename_' + i + '" name="coursename_' + i + '" class="course_list"><option value="" >--- Select ---</option>"';
          content += data;
          content += '</select></br>';

          // Insert the `content` into DOM here, you cannot return due to the async nature of AJAX
        }
      });

    })(i); // you have to pass `i` into a function, otherwise when ajax complete, i will equal to `option + 1`

  }
}
```

Comment: Alright, Great! Is it possible to set a time interval to trigger the call every 3 seconds?

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student you can use setInterval function

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not used return statement in addNewCourse(), try `return content;` after completion of Ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#courses_offered').change(function() {
        var option = $(this).val();
        showFields(option);
        return false;
    });
    function showFields(option){ 
        var content = '';
        for (var i = 1; i <= option; i++){
            function addNewCourse() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "coursesOffered.php",
                    data: { value : option},
                    success: function(data){
                    content += '<div id="course_'+i+'"><label>Course # '+i+'</label><br /><label>Course Name:</label> <select id="coursename_'+i+'" name="coursename_'+i+'" class="course_list"><option value="" >--- Select ---</option>"';
                    content += data;
                    content += '</select></div></br>';              
                    }
                });
                return content;
            }          
            content = addNewCourse();
        }
        $('#course_catalog').html(content);    
    }
});
```